# Connectedness of a set consisting of limit points

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and
$A=\{y\in\mathbb{R}:y=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}f(x_n),x_n\to \infty\}$

What are the properties of $A$  which are always true:

1.The set is compact

2.The set is a singleton

3.The set is connected

I think it is connected  always because it is a set of limit points of a sequence under the continuous map. It may not be compact as the sequence diverges.Any ideas Thanks.

Comment: image of connected set is connected. connected subsets in real lines are juat intervals. by your definition, A is closure of an interval which is a closed interval.

Comment: I am confused by your set $A$. What if $f$ is unbounded? Then isn't $A$ empty?

Comment: @EthanAlwaise  This was asked in an exam[TIFR].It was given as is and I too am confused

Comment: I think $A$ is either empty or a singleton. $A$ is the limit of $f$ as $x \to \infty$, so either it doesn't exist and $A$ is empty or it is exists and then $A$ is a singleton. So then $A$ is always connected and compact.

Comment: @EthanAlwaise I checked the answer key:it says it is connected and not singleton or compact.So is it empty?

Comment: It could be a singleton, e.g. if $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2+1}$, where the set equals $\{0\}$.

Comment: It could be empty e.g. for $f(x) = x$.

Comment: But if is non-empty, it is connected.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma considering the extended real number system, can we say that than the set is connected always

Comment: For $f(x)=\sin x$, $A$ would be the interval $[-1,1]$. For $f(x)=x\sin x$, $A=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Brilliant. So then, connectedness is the only constant,isn't it?

Comment: It still needs to be proved. I think I see an $\epsilon$ argument for it but not sure I can stay awake long enough to write it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Claim:** $A$ is an interval and hence connected.

**Proof:** Suppose $x,y \in A$ (Wlog assume $x>y)$ by definition of $A$ there exist $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ diverging to infinity such that $f(x_n) \to x$ and $f(y_n) \to y$.Suppose $z \in (x,y)$,note that  for $n$ sufficiently large we have $f(x_n)>z>f(y_n)$ (Why?).Hence by [Intermediate Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) there exist $z_n$ between  $x_n$ and $y_n$  such that....

Can you complete from here?

Comment: Much simpler than my proof and avoids the use of $\epsilon$ altogether. It may be the case that $y_n<x_n$  but that does not detract from the argument since clearly in that case there is still the $z_n \in (y_n,x_n)$.

Comment: Clarification: The $\epsilon$ is not actually avoided since it is required in answering the "why?"

Comment: Dear @JohnWaylandBales: Thank you,i have edited my answer!

Answer (score 2):

Addendum: The first two are easily shown to be false by a single example, $f(x)=x\sin(x)$, which leaves only the third.

$A$ could be a singleton as in the case of $f(x)=\arctan(x)$ in which case $A$ would be connected. But suppose $A$ is not a singleton.

Let $p<q$ denote two elements of $A$ and let $\{p_k\}\to \infty$ and $\{q_k\}\to \infty$ such that $\{f(p_k)\}\to p$ and $\{f(q_k)\}\to q$.

Pick an $r$ such that $p<r<q$ and let $0<\epsilon<\min\{r-p,q-r\}$.

Pick a sequence satisfying

$(1)\quad w_0$ is the first element $p_m$ of $\{p_k\}$ satisfying $|p-p_m|<\epsilon$

$(2)\quad w_1$ is the first element $q_m$ of $\{q_k\}$ satisfying $|q-q_m|<\epsilon$ and $w_0<q_m$.

$(3)$ For $n>0$, pick $w_{2n}$ the first element $p_m$ of $\{p_k\}$ satisfying $|p-p_m|<\epsilon$ and $w_{2n-1}<p_m$.

$(4)$  For $n>0$, pick $w_{2n+1}$  the first element $q_m$ of $\{q_k\}$ satisfying $|q-q_m|<\epsilon$ and $w_{2n}<q_m$.

So $\{w_{2n}\}$ is an increasing subsequence of $\{p_n\}$ and $\{w_{2n+1}\}$ is an increasing subsequence of $\{q_n\}$ and $w_{2n}<w_{2n+1}$ for $n\ge0$.

Since $f$ is continuous, for each $n\ge0$ one can pick an $r_n\in(w_{2n},w_{2n+1})$ satisfying $f(r_n)=r$.

Then $\{r_k\}\to\infty$ and $\{f(r_k)\}\to r$.

So $r\in A$. Therefore $[p,q]\subset A$.

Since $A$ is an arcwise connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$, $A$ is connected.